# Limit when an expoent goes to infinity

Tags: limits, infinity

Please could someone help me and see if my solutions are correct for these two limits

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$.

Case 1
$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \cfrac{y^n}{y^{n+1}}=\lim_{y \to \infty} y^{n-(n+1)}= \lim_{y \to \infty} \cfrac{1}{y}=0$$

Case 2
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{y^n}{y^{n+1}}$$

In this case, I consider that I cannot manipulate the exponents in the same way as in case 1. So let be

Case 2

$$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{y^n}{y^{n+1}}$$

$$\sqrt[n]{L} = \sqrt[n]{\lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{y^n}{y^{n+1}}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\cfrac{y^n}{y^{n+1}}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{y^{n/n}}{y^{(n+1)/n}}$$

$$\sqrt[n]{L} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{y^{1}}{y^{1+1/n}}=1$$

And thus,

$$ L = 1^n = 1$$

Comment: The first step you have done is just algebra, it has nothing to do with limits.  So certainly you can do it the same way in case 1 and case 2.

Comment: @David I don't think so. Algebra works quite nice when you do not involve $\infty$. In some way, I am asking $\lim_{n \to \infty}n-(n+1)$. Or also $\infty - \infty$?.

Comment: I'm only talking about the first step.  This is **before** you take the limit and therefore it does not involve $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good.

For case 1, the denominator grows faster and thus the limit goes to 0.

The second case is wrong however. It can be simplified like this:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{y^n}{y^{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{y}$$

In other words, you can use the same method as for case 1.

Comment: Thank you. Let us see if other guys accord with my additional argument. What do you think?

Comment: After reading the other answer I realised I was wrong about case 2. I've changed the details now.

Comment: Did you add something else? @naslundx

Answer (score 1):

No, for all positive n, case 2 is the constant 1/y. Why the doubt that you cannot "manipulate the exponents in the same way"?

For all n, $\frac{y^n}{y^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{y}$. To convince yourself of this, plug in say, 2 for n, then plug in 3, then plug in 4 etc. But you could just as easily write $\frac{y^n}{y^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{y^{(n + 1) - n}} = \frac{1}{y}$.

To see the error in the "proof" take the n-th root of any positive number C and then take the limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{C} = 1$$

And for all n, $$1^{n} = 1$$

Nevertheless, this does not prove that C = 1. (In your case 2, C is 1/y.)

Edit:

What the above argument shows is that taking the limit of the n-th root of any positive number destroys all information on what postive number you started with. Similarly, multiplying a number by zero destroys all infomation on what number you started with. Taking the n-th root and raising to the n-th power are inverses of each other, but not if you take limits in between.

Also, I agree that Case 1 is perfectly fine.

Another edit:

The particular part that is incorrect is that in fact,

$$\sqrt[n]{\lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{y^n}{y^{n+1}}} \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\cfrac{y^n}{y^{n+1}}}$$

The problem is that the $n$ outside of the limit and the $n$ inside are different. The one on the outside is a fixed number (it doesn't approach infinity). But once it is put inside the limit, it is no longer fixed. The n underneath the limit is a dummy variable. i.e.,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{y^n}{y^{n+1}} = \lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{y^j}{y^{j+1}}.$$

It is true that

$$\sqrt[n]{\lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{y^j}{y^{j+1}}} = \lim_{j \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{y^j}{y^{j+1}}}$$

but then we see that the n and the j do not simplify.

Comment: Let $p=n$ and $k=n+1$
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{p}{k} =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{n}{n+1} =   \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{n}{n+1}\cfrac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} =1$$

That is

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{p}{k} =1 $$

$p/k$ goes to $1$ if and only if $p-k$ goes to $0$.

Case 2

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{y^p}{y^k} = \lim_{n \to \infty} y^{p-k} =\lim_{n \to \infty} y^{0} = 1   $$

The result $1/y$ implies that $p/k$ does not go to $1$, which seems to me that contradicts the notion of infinity. @David ?

Comment: No, the statement p/k goes to 1 iff p-k goes to 0 is false. Let f(n) = n^2 + n and g(n) = n^2. Then f(n) - g(n) approaches infinity. Yest still f(n)/g(n) approaches 1. In your case, p-k is the constant 1.

Comment: Oops. p-k is the constant -1.

Comment: Dear @AndrewKelley, I am not confident with this reasoning. I found this affirmation in "Cauchi's Cours d'analyse": When variables remain independent, the values of $x/y = 0/0 = M((- \infty, + \infty))$ or $x/y = \infty / \infty =-\infty /- \infty= M((0,+ \infty))$. When I take $y^n$ I mean a function independent of $y^{(n+1)}$. And therefore, for $y<1$, it would be $M((-\infty,+ \infty))$ and for $y=1$, it would be $1$, and for $y>1$ it will be $M((0,+ \infty))$. Where $M((a,b))$ denotes any value betwen the limits of $a$ and $b$. What do you think?

Comment: I like your approach when you use `destroy` the information. I also think that when someone just cancel terms $n$ from two different functions, I think it would be also destroying the information about the individuality of each function. @andrew-kelley

Comment: Please see my extra edit. Also, I do not understand your comment that references "Cauchi's Cours d'analyse." Let me add another thing explaining "destroy." Take any real number we want, say 10. Multiplying and dividing by $n$ dosn't do anything, correct? But still, notice that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{10}{n} = 0.$ But if we try to undo the dividing by "$n$" by then multiplying 0 by "$n$", we get $n \times 0 = 0$. Does this show that 10 = 0? No. Nevertheless, what I'm saying is that taking the limit eliminated the information on which number we started with, namely 10.

Comment: I got your point. It makes sense. What I am not happy it is the fact that when you have two functions, I think each of the two as different systems, which in this case have the input $n$. Let your affirmation " Let f(n) = n^2 + n and g(n) = n^2. Then f(n) - g(n) approaches infinity. ". Obviously m(n)=n approaches infinity when n goes to infinity. But if f(n) and g(n) are seen independent (as Cauchy satates) both functions goes to infinity, and therefore we will have $\infty - \infty$ gives $M((-\infty,+\infty))$.

Comment: When you cancel $n^2 - n^2$ you imagine that before the functions approach infinity, you can make some conventional manipulations. I think that the priority is to solve the function. Let us remember that the following equality should hold $lim_{n \to \infty}(f(n)-g(n))= lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)-lim_{n \to \infty}g(n)$. And thank you again for helping me in my doubts.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.whfreeman.com/Catalog/static/whf/taalmankohnpreview/images/c01Limits_TK.pdf page 94. If it is $\lim_{y \to \infty} \cfrac{y^n}{y^{n+1}} = 1/y$ $N$ may also be $0$, which does not make sense for the formal definition of limit.

Comment: For a given $n$, $\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y^n}{y^{n+1}} = 0.$ It is not $\frac{1}{y}.$ In that case, $y$ is a dummy variable.

Comment: Sorry, in the last comment, I would like to say $n \to \infty;$. That allows $n$ be 0. What do you think?

Comment: In your comment about the difference of $j$ and $n$, I can build my affirmation instead of $\sqrt[n]{L}$ I can write $\lim_{n \to \infty}L^{1/n}$. In such situation, both $n$ would be equal.

Comment: I plan to stop commenting on this. No, it is incorrect to rewrite $\sqrt[n]{L}$ as $lim_{n \to \infty}L^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Please read my answer again. If you do not believe my statement after "Another edit" that starts out as "The particular part that is incorrect is that in fact, ..." then, please think about it for a while. Also, note that the other guy agrees with me. If, after thinking about it, you still disagree, please ask another question here (or ask a math tutor) why what I said in my post is true.

Comment: And by "ask another question here", I mean, create a new question.